# count Number of 1 Bits in java

Tags: java, bit

I encountered a strange problem while doing an leetcode problem. This is about bits representation in Java.

> Write a function that takes an unsigned integer and returns the number of ’1' bits it has (also known as the Hamming weight).
>
> For example, the 32-bit integer ’11' has binary representation 00000000000000000000000000001011, so the function should return 3.

My solution is

```
public class Solution {
// you need to treat n as an unsigned value
    public int hammingWeight(int n) {
        int count = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < 32; ++i){
            if((n >>> i) % 2 == 1){
                ++count;
            }
        }
        return count;
    }
}
```

This code is not accepted because of the input case:

4294967295 (11111111111111111111111111111111)

I reviewed the bit representation of integer in java but still do not know the problem of the solution?

Could anyone help me?

Comment: Try `Long.bitCount(4294967295L)`.

Answer (score 18):

```
public int hammingWeight(int n) {
    return Integer.bitCount(n);
}
```

> [Integer.bitCount(int i)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#bitCount-int-)
>
> Returns the number of one-bits in the two's complement binary
>   representation of the specified int value.

Answer (score 7):

The issue is performing modulo when you want a bitwise `&`. Something like,

```
public static int hammingWeight(int n) {
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 32; ++i) {
        if (((n >>> i) & 1) == 1) {
            ++count;
        }
    }
    return count;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int c = -1;
    System.out.println(hammingWeight(c));
}
```

Outputs (as expected)

```
32
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your prompt reply. Could you please tell me why I got the result 31 from my code? If I right shift the original value (11111111111111111111111111111111) 31 times, shouldn't I get 1 and finally get the result 32?

Comment: @YunLi because the input value is -1. -1%2 = -1, you could change the condition to !=0 and it will work for your example.

Comment: The OP has correctly used `>>>` so it really shouldn't need `long`. The fix is purely the use of `& 1` over `% 2`

Comment: @weston Edited and tested.

Answer (score 3):

Java uses twos compliment. So the negative bit is the far left one. That means if you have a number greater than `Integer.MAX_VALUE` your input will be a negative number. When you do `%2`the sign remains unchanged. An alternative would be to use `&1`which will change the sign bit. After the first iteration, and you have done a bit shift, the sign bit will be zero.

Comment: Thanks so much @matt